# Unable to create/terminate instances (I'm the admin)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Something weird is going on for the first time. I use AWS for all of my infrastructure but for some reason, it seems like the management console is confirming all of my actions, but it's not doing any of them.

For example, in this case I started a new instance, and it confirmed it:

[image]

However, after clicking on the instance name, it takes me to the EC2 instance page and there's no instance:

[image]

The same thing is happening when I try to terminate an instance. It says instance successfully terminated, but the status never changes from "Running" to "Terminating" on an old EC2 instance I deployed for testing purposes.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: New console is poorly designed, at best. Still lots of bugs. Try to press `X` in the search button, to show everything and refresh.

Comment: Tried to do that too unfortunately, but no luck :(

Comment: Then double check the region. maybe it takes you to the wrong region where you deployed your instance. Alternatlively check with aws cli

Comment: I thought the same thing and double checked, lol, but it doesn't appear any new instances have been started in any other region. Very strange.

Comment: But have you checked with AWS CLI?

Comment: Shows the same thing as the console, with the exception of the instance that I would consider to be "stuck" in a "Running" state although I've terminated it.

Comment: So maybe you have still leftovers from most recent [issues](https://status.aws.amazon.com/) AWS EC2. They write it resolved, but maybe not fully yet for everyone.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot! Will contact AWS Support. Really appreciate the help troubleshooting!

Comment: Can you try switching to oldder version of ec2 console and then try things

Comment: Must be an internal bug or something. In the old console, it says "Successfully launched" just like the new console, but then the filtered results show: `An error occurred fetching instance data: The instance ID 'i-0c99186fa5240e324' does not exist`. I also noticed that the "stuck" instance showed "unable to describe instance status" next to the status

Comment: AWS mentioned they're having an issue in us-west-2 right now. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you don't mind, I could provide an answer with the link to the issues I indicated?

Comment: Absolutely @Marcin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

AWS has just had internal issues in the US regions for EC2 as listed in [Service Health Dashboard](https://status.aws.amazon.com/).

Specifically, the EC2 issues for `us-east-1` regions have been marked as resolved, but **new issues in** `us-west-2` has appeared and they are still unresolved. At present they are listed to affect AWS Batch, but its possible that EC2 is also affected to some extend.

> 6:45 PM PDT We are investigating increased transitions to INVALID of some AWS Batch Compute Environments in the US-WEST-2 Region.
> 7:12 PM PDT We can confirm increased transitions to INVALID of some AWS Batch Compute Environments in the US-WEST-2 Region.